# is there a method of sorting a mongoose model by the sum of 2 fields?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

i have those models

```json
[
{"trisWin":18,"trisLost":2,"pongWin":4,"_id":"6068c0c237326d13706569aa","username":"Tommaso","password":"$2a$10$2TiaY12yCcRKWleDkXCeGe1ujJf8Liv5WBzsxFjGesrZR.KtakQtW","__v":0},
{"trisWin":13,"trisLost":0,"pongWin":10,"_id":"606b838a81811a3734a9c717","username":"Test1234","password":"$2a$10$0KoOhIRzjQlsMho0rmFsLeoorTn4bjL3eGofRQuy.cc//3zIttWsa","__v":0},
{"trisWin":9,"trisLost":0,"pongWin":2,"_id":"6068ca2ad9587c2b2c8df467","username":"Giacomo","password":"$2a$10$h24RPkGssur29K1WM5aCuOVO6Uw7cY9DD.s9nOU1iEp4qb6TxSuvu","__v":0}
]
```

i want to sort them by the sum of "pongWin" and "trisWin"

i have tryied this `const result = await User.find().sort({ trisWin: -1 })`

it works, but only with the trisWin variable

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add the field to the object that you pass to the sort method.

```
User.find().sort({ trisWin: -1, pongWin: -1 })
```

Comment: But this will sort based on first `trisWin` and then if `trisWin` have same values then will sort based on `pongWin`. But it won't based on `trisWin` + `pongWin`

Comment: My fault, I did not properly read your question. Vishnu give the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort on a sum of two fields without using aggregation.
However, aggregation is quite slow and it doesn't persist the output.

What you can do is create a new field on each document as `trisTotal` and then sort based on that field.
If the `trisWin` and ``` trisLoss``keep updating, you can also update the ``` trisTotal`in the same update query that you use for updating`trisWin`and`trisLoss```.

```
User.update_many(filter={}, update= {$set: {trisTotal: { $trisWin + $trisLost}}})
const result = await User.find().sort({ trisTotal: -1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate pipeline for this

```js
const result = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: { // new field to hold the total
      total: {
        $sum: ["$pongWin", "$trisWin"],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {  // Sorting based on total
      total: -1,
    },
  },
  {
    $unset: ["total"], // Removing the newly added total field after sorting 
  },
]);
```